# webgl not using the entire canvas space

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have a spinning 3D letter "F". For some reason, the "F" is not drawn in the top 20% of the canvas. See this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c948jos0/.

The render function:

```
var rX = 0;
var rY = 0;

gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
gl.canvas.width = 400;
gl.canvas.height = 200;
gl.clearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1.0);

function render(){
    rX += Math.PI/64;
    rY += Math.PI/128;

    var projection = make2DProjection(gl.canvas.clientWidth,gl.canvas.clientHeight,400);
    var translation = makeTranslation(200,50,0);
    var rotX = makeXRotation(rX);
    var rotY = makeYRotation(rY);

    var mat = matrixMultiply(rotX,rotY);
    mat = matrixMultiply(mat,translation);
    mat = matrixMultiply(mat,projection);
    uniforms["u_matrix"](new Float32Array(mat));

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES,0, 16*6);

    setTimeout(render,33);
}

render();
```

The matrices:

```
function makeTranslation(tx, ty, tz) {
    return [
        1,  0,  0,  0,
        0,  1,  0,  0,
        0,  0,  1,  0,
        tx, ty, tz, 1
    ];
}

function makeXRotation(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

    return [
        1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, c, s, 0,
        0, -s, c, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    ];
}

function makeYRotation(angleInRadians) {
    var c = Math.cos(angleInRadians);
    var s = Math.sin(angleInRadians);

    return [
        c, 0, -s, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        s, 0, c, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1
    ];
}


function make2DProjection(width, height, depth) {
    // Note: This matrix flips the Y axis so 0 is at the top.
    return [
        2 / width, 0, 0, 0,
        0, -2 / height, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 2 / depth, 0,
        -1, 1, 0, 1
    ];
}
```

I have been following http://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-orthographic.html so I figure I must have changed something I shouldn't have or made a typo. The problem is I cant figure out what. I think its the make2DProjection matrix not setting the origin to the top left corner of canvas, but the same code is working in the tutorial so I dont know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas element is initialized with 300x150 dimensions and so is your viewport.
When changing the canvas size after you acquired the webgl context you also need to set the  [`viewport`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/1.0/#2.3) using

`gl.viewport(x, y, width, height)`

I've adjusted [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c948jos0/7/) and added a second canvas with an outline so you can see the difference.

Unless you have a specific need to only cover part of the canvas a recommended way to do this is.

```
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
```

Comment: Ah I see. I had a feeling it was something like this. Do you have any recommendations on a good source to learn webgl? I feel cheated now that all the tutorials I looked at didn't mention this.